# jquery not working inside of html script tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cdn

This question is not a duplicate!
I have tried many methods, yet they havent worked. I cannot tell what i am doing wrong. I have the src in the top script tags and i used $(document).ready
Here is the code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<button id="button">Button</button>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    alert("Test");
  });
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined and Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: That means you've not loaded jQuery properly. I can see there's a reference to it in the HTML, but I can only assume the path is incorrect and needs to be fixed.

Comment: You are no loading jQuery from the CDN.

Comment: Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Google : `src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"` or Microsoft: `src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"`

Comment: Ok thank you This worked

Answer (score 0):

Does the file `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` exist in the same path as your html file?

If not, you need to [download jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) or link to a CDN instead of a local file.

Answer (score -1):

Your "jquery-3.3.1.min.js" file may not present in your working path. Make sure you provided the correct path or else you can load jquery from CDN directly.

Or

Try moving the script inside 'head' tag.